# Selecting average total where an associated table has id present

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm fairly new to SQL and I'm trying to answer this question:

What is the average order total, where product X is present.

We have an orders table, and line items. An order has many line items, which again store the `product_id`.

```
SELECT
    avg(total) 
FROM
    orders 
WHERE 
    (shipment_state = 'shipped')
    AND (delivery_date BETWEEN '2017-09-11' AND '2017-09-18');
```

is what I have now and that is working, however I do not know how to fetch and calculate it based on another table (in this case `line_item`)

Comment: tables structure please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `exists`:

```
SELECT AVG(o.total) 
FROM orders o
WHERE o.shipment_state = 'shipped' AND
      o.delivery_date BETWEEN '2017-09-11' AND '2017-09-18' AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM orderlines ol
              WHERE ol.order_id = o.order_id AND
                    ol.product_id = X
             );
```

Notes:

- When you have more than one table in a query, always use table aliases and qualified column names.
- When working with dates, `BETWEEN` is not recommended.  The recommended construct is `o.delivery_date >= '2017-09-11' AND o.delivery_date < '2017-09-19'`.  This works for both dates and date/time values.

Comment: What does the SELECT 1 do? What does the 1 represent?

Comment: @SebastianJenningsAlmnes . . . `EXISTS` just checks to see if a row is returned.  The value(s) on the row are immaterial.  `1` is easy to type.